# Web port forward with dynamic IP

Tags: server, redirect, portforwarding, port80

Soooo here's the situation.

```
I have a domain with register.com.
I have a server at my home but I also have a dynamic IP.
My ISP blocks port 80.
```

I can set up something to update my IP address but have yet to find a free and easy solution for port forwarding (preferably a one-step solution).  Does anyone know of a solution to work around this?  I tried noip and afraid.org but afraid.org doesnt let me do a port forward and noip wants me to pay for a web redirect using custom dns or something.  I cant update the IP on the fly with code on register.com and noip only lets me update the IP of my server and there is no static IP to place an A record on register.com with.  Im a little fuzzy still with A records and CNAME but from what I can tell, I can only use an IP with an A record and not a port or website name and a CNAME doesnt have enough data to do a forward how I want.  PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: This is not programming-related; nominating to move to https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing apples and oranges.  In the absence of an explicit port number, a HTTP URL will connect to port 80 on the IP address.  So `http://example.com/` is shorthand for `http://example.com:80/` and the only part you can influence via DNS is which IP address `example.com` resolves to.

Dynamic DNS will happily let you update the IP address for `example.com` on the fly with a fairly tolerable latency, so I think we can actually ignore that part of the question.  I see you already discovered [noip](http://noip.com/) for this.

What you can do:

1. Use a different port; for example, http://example.com:8080/.  This probably still violates your ISP's AUP, but if you can find a port they don't firewall, this will technically work.

   A variant would be to use HTTPS which uses a different port number; so https://example.com/ is https://example.com:443/ with the added benefit of an encrypted protocol.
2. Have (a friend host) a reverse proxy outside your ISP's network.  Then http://example.com/ will resolve to your friend's server, but behind the scenes, he will do http://you.example.com:8080/ to fetch the content (where `you.example.com` is now your home server).  This is fundamentally the same as option #1 but with a bit more lipstick on the pig.  Also this hugely complicates anything which requires close interaction between server and client (AJAX etc).
3. Host your content elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

So this has been awhile but I havent logged on since I resolved this.  My only option turned out to just be hosted elsewhere.  I went with freehosting.com and any content I need I just use php scripts to grab content.  The cool part is using windows task manager to update my server's dynamic-based IP on the freehosting so I can use that in scripts.  Crude workaround but It works.